# SQL Query to clean up messed data from .txt file and export it to excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of datas in .txt file and it includes all numbers, there is no | between each column which make the data completely messed up. The rules is to clean up the messed up data into 24 columns in excel.

for example in the.txt it shows:

```
2020053009701665607077010415CILS3000007960IDR0970133560700001041502000000149ADAM JOHN ROBERT                     0000772770133.79 00000002200000.00 0000911000000.00 0000000000000.00 009.990 A                  201509092030040920190809201908093                        N10000004747456.45 X970137560730000001       0000002760666.67 0000506529333.33 0000006440295.42 00P00              0006900000000.00         0000002011000.00 0000003323460.07 0000106460646.14 909563X197006200051222019170902019890000987
```

while I need the data to be like:

```
20200530|097016656070|77010415CILS300000|7960IDR09701|33560700001041502000000149|ADAM JOHN ROBERT|0000772770133.79|00000002200000.00|0000911000000.00|0000000000000.00|009.990 A|201509092030040920190809201908093|N10000004747456.45|X970137560730000001      |0000002760666.67|0000506529333.33|0000006440295.42|00P00              0006900000000.00|0000002011000.00|0000003323460.07|0000106460646.14|909563X19700620005122|201917090|2019890000987
```

and at the end I will be exporting all the data to excel.

Is there anyway I could do this with a SQL scripting???

Comment: Whih dbms are you talking about?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Comment: If you have the existing data as a .txt file, and the target is an Excel file, then it sounds like importing into an SQL database is not really a necessary step in the solution. If the .txt file has fixed length fields, then you can open this in Excel using it's import wizard. You may get some mileage from using my Excel "Fixed Width Tool": https://inboxly.net/annotations/fixed_width_tool.html

Answer (score 0):

use `SUBSTRING` and `concat` as follows:

```
concat(substring(your_string,1,8),'|', 
       substring(your_string,9,12),'|',
       ... so on
      )
```